# SSRS 2012 Expression with Switch not working as expected

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have an expression in SSRS that looks at a client #, county and eventually a service type to determine if an adjustment needs to be made.

The problem I have is that my Switch statement seems to always pick up the default value instead of acting on the service type.

This is my SSRS expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!ClientNo.Value="2139",
    IIF(Fields!County.Value="RIVERSIDE" or Fields!County.Value="SAN BERNARDINO",
        Switch(
            UCase(Fields!ServiceType.Value)="NOT FOUND",-29.50, 
            UCase(Fields!ServiceType.Value)="PERSONAL",-20.50, 
            UCase(Fields!ServiceType.Value)="SUB",-20.50, 
            True,Fields!ServiceType.Value
        )
    ,"")
,"")
```

The record that I'm looking at has a service type of "Not Found" and satisfies the criteria of the expression (see image).
[Record that needs an adjustment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul6kR.jpg)

I cannot figure out why the Switch statement is not acting on "Not Found".  Instead it drops to the default value and displays "Not Found".  The adjustment amount should appear between the word "Service Fee" and the amount of $69.00.

In my SP, I perform an ltrim/rtrim on service type so that should remove extra spaces.

The expression looks straightforward to me.  I don't know what I'm missing.

Thanks

Edited to correct spelling in San Bernardino

Comment: It looks good to me. Try outputting the default as "&"+Ucase(Fields!ServiceType.Value)+"&" that way you can see what it looks like when the comparison is occurring and watch for any extra spaces in the string between the ampersands. Also btw you got a typo in SAN BERNARDINO.

Comment: Thanks @Lucky, you're right. Will fix that.

Comment: any luck looking outputting the string? Wondering if you found an extra space or weird character in there.

Comment: @Lucky, it turned out to be a combination of things.  Some records contained extra spaces at the end of the the county field so I trimmed those in the query and I also needed to add UCase to the county checks to make it consistent.  Once I did that, the expression worked.  Thanks for your suggestions.